# PHP extracton foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, extract

Please can someone help me,I have the following array and would like to extract the data

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["from"]=>
    string(7) "coltest"
    ["to"]=>
    string(13) "+447000000000"
    ["body"]=>
    string(12) "Hello World!"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["from"]=>
    string(8) "coltest2"
    ["to"]=>
    string(14) "+447000000001"
    ["body"]=>
    string(13) "Hello World2!"
  }
}
```

I can extract the first one using

```
extract($array[0]);
echo("$from $to $body");
```

But I would like to pass each $from, $to and $body to my suppliers API - I am guessing i need to write a foreach statement but I dont know where to begin

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want those separate variables in each iteration of a foreach loop, you can use [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

```
foreach (array as list($from, $to, $body)) {
    echo "$from $to $body";
}
```

`extract` will also work in foreach, but I usually avoid using it. It can have unintended consequences if it's accidentally applied to the wrong thing, and it can potentially make it difficult to see where a variable came from when you're reading the code.

```
foreach (array as $item) {
    extract($item);
    echo "$from $to $body";
}
```

But keep in mind you don't really need separate variables at all.

```
foreach (array as $item) {
    echo "$item[from] $item[to] $item[body]";
}
```

By the way, `echo` is [not a function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php#reserved.keywords), so you don't need to use parentheses with it.

Comment: Thank you, - been spending hours trying to understand how to do it - and it two lines and 2 minutes you have done it - ... foreach (array as $item) {
    echo "$item[from] $item[to] $item[body]"; .. is perfect!
}

Comment: Welcome :-) It can be a bit confusing at first, but it gets easier.

Comment: Is it possible to the varibles to a function ? - I have just done function callAPI($from,$to,$body)
{
    echo "$from $to $body";
}

foreach ($array as $item) {
    extract($item);
 callAPI($from,$to,$body)
}

Comment: Sure, there are different ways to do that. The simplest way is to just call the function in the loop, using `$item['from']` etc as its arguments.

Comment: What you did looks like it should work, though. It's just missing a semicolon after the function call in the foreach loop.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest using an IDE or a syntax-aware text editor. It can highlight easy-to-miss typos like that as you're writing the code. Good luck!